# Is it possible to filter related products based on some of it's attributes on the product view page?

Tags: magento, attributes

I am new to magento and looking for a solution. Is it possible to filter related products based on some of it's attributes on the product view page? I have a product and there are 100s of related products associated with it. I want customers to filter these related products based on their attributes on the product view page itself. Is it possible? Please help me.

Regards, Pallab

Comment: Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The template (Magento 1.9.1.0 version) for this is located in: **frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml** template and the Block class associated with this template is: **Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Related.php** and the method is: **protected function _prepareData()** where the related products collection is being fetched. You will have to setup your filters as you need, most likely by using JavaScript and finding the products that match the selected (filtered) attributes by the customer.

For more thorough answer, I will need more information about how these filters should look like and work.

Comment: Thanks #zokibtmkd, let me try this